# CSS placeholder issue in HTML5

Tags: css, html

This is the code I have tried:

**HTML5:**

```
<section class="featured">
    <p><img src="img/Defense.png" />ABOUVESTIBULUM ANTE IPSUM PRIMIS IN FAUCIBUS ORCILUCTUS</p>
    <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="SUBSCRIBE TO OUR NEWSLETTER"/>
    </form>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.featured { 
    background-color: darkgray;
    color:#fff; 
    padding:10px;
    display: flex;  
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
input[type=text] {
    border-radius:0px;
    padding: 14px 86px 14px 18px;
    margin-left: 164px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
form {
    float:right;
    margin:0;   
}
```

My page looks like this: http://postimg.org/image/6vlweo5sz/5d213f6c/

May I know why the placeholder content is not displayed properly?

Is this approach correct or not?

Comment: Post the whole code. The placeholder is changed somewhere. It works fine in Chrome. Search for "SUBSCRIBE TO OUR NE" in all files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your CSS input properties to this:

```
input[type=text] {
    border-radius:0px;
    padding: 14px 18px 14px 18px;
    margin-left: 164px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    width:240px;
}
```

your `padding right` makes no sense at all, what you need to give is a width to the input element. Alternatively, if you don't want it to be that wide, add a smaller font-size, like `font-size:10px;`

I have added bot options to a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cdfwbavx/)

Comment: when resize the window, it shows like this http://s7.postimg.org/bjzabwduj/Untitled_1_copy.png. It is not correct right?

Comment: no, but this is related to the rest of the layout of your page, please open another question and include your code, you can use my fiddle as starting point, then fork it and paste the code here so we can see it and we can help you (either way, it's an easy fix, the only thing needed is to know your layout and that's it)

Answer (score 1):

You may try using `size` attribute:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="SUBSCRIBE TO OUR NEWSLETTER" size="45"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is too much **padding** for the input box.

```
padding: 14px 86px 14px 18px;
```

The order is `top - right - bottom - left`. You can adjust the second and the fourth value.

If you need that `padding`, increase the `width`.

Another thing that could be useful in other similar cases is:

```
input[placeholder] { 
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
}
```

because it specifies the behavior if the text is longer that your box.

Comment: I want to look like my posted image, and need to change only in full view of placeholder value.